# Infopath view rule basing off existing form column

Tags: 2010, infopath, infopath-rules, infopath-view

I have an InfoPath form that switches views based off users. That works fine. The form library has a column to track workflow progress. After the form has been approved by all approvers the column is set to "Approved" and the form only opens as read-only after that.

When I click Add document and go to key in another form that form is in read-only mode like it's looking at the other forms approval column.

I'm sure it's just a rule fix, but why is a new form pulling an old forms column?

Comment: What is the default view set to? It might have accidentally been set to the read only view.

Comment: InfoPath still shows New Application as my Default View